# Zend Framework and controller injection to solve tight coupling

Tags: php, zend-framework, dependency-injection, zend-framework2

Similar to ASP.NET MVC, I would like to achieve loose coupling on the controller and their dependencies.

I would like to achieve the following:

```
class TimesheetController extends AbstractActionController
{    
    private $userRepository;

    function __Construct()
    {
        $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
        $this->userRepository = $sm->get('Application\Model\Concrete\TGUserRepository');
    }

    // ... becomes

    function __Construct( IUserRepository $userRepo ) // the controller is injected with a bound repository so I do not have to implicitly specify it in the construct
    {
        $this->userRepository = $userRepo;
    }

    // And this is my action

    public function ListAction()
    {
        $users = $this->userRepository->Users();

        $view = new ViewModel( array( "Users" => $users ) );

            $secondarySidebarView = new ViewModel();
            $secondarySidebarView->setTemplate('something/poo');

        $view->addChild($secondarySidebarView, 'something');
        return $view;
    }

    // .... and more
}
```

How do I go about doing this?

I would imagine there would be a binding function that says when something needs IUserRepository, go make a TGUserRepository

```
Bind("IUserRepository", "TGUserRepository");
```

I have seen Laravel does it exactly how I want:

http://laravel.com/docs/ioc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controller are called exactly the same way as Services in ZF2, so when you declare a new controller in the config/module.config.php, instead of registrering it in 'invokables', you can register it in 'factories' for exemple :

```
'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'Application\Controller\Index'          => 'Application\Controller\IndexController',
    ),
    'factories' => array(
        'Application\Controller\Timesheet' => function ($sm) {
             $userRepository = $sm->get('Application\Model\Concrete\TGUserRepository');
             $controller = new \Application\Controller\TimesheetController($userRepository);
             $controller->setServiceLocator($sm);
             return $controller;
        },
    ),
),
```

By the way, when you use service locator to get instances and services, you are limiting the coupling to the ServiceLocator only, you can easily 'mock' a service in test, or replace the service by another to do the job.

Of course ServiceLocator become a huge stack of service and instance as the application grow. I become less readable and hard to know 'what you have inside'. I understand your point of view by passing exactly what you expect (and is needed) in your controller.